# Create two vendor chunks in webpack

Tags: webpack

In my current webpack setting, I have one cacheGroup for everything in the `node_modules` folder:

```
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
            "vendors": {
                test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                name: "vendors",
                chunks: "all",
                priority: 1,
            },
        }
    },
}
```

I want a separate vendor file specifically moment-timezone. Everything else stays in `vendors`, but moment-timezone should be its own file. How do I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe 2 entry point can help you to do that ?

In your webpack

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        "moment-timezone": "vendor-moment.js",
        "common-vendor": "common-vendor.js"
    },
```

So the moment-timezone file will be something like this

```
import "moment";
```

When you run webpack you will have 2 js file 1 for moment timezone 1 for another vendor script